# ADC trigger Timer1 using dsPIC33CK64MC105

Tags: adc, pic, microchip

I currently working on the dsPIC33CK64MC105 controller. I tried to configure ADC triggered by Timer1 I have done step as in the datasheet but I didn't get the ADC data can anyone correct me for the mistake I have done?

```
#include<xc.h>
#include "mcc_generated_files/system.h"

/*
                         Main application
 */
int ADC_result_0,ADC_result_1;
void EnableAndCalibrate()
{
    // Set initialization time to maximum
    ADCON5Hbits.WARMTIME = 15;
    // Turn on ADC module
    ADCON1Lbits.ADON = 1;
    // Turn on analog power for shared core
    ADCON5Lbits.SHRPWR = 1;
    // Wait when the core 0 is ready for operation
    while(ADCON5Lbits.SHRRDY == 0);
    // Turn on digital power to enable triggers to the shared core
    ADCON3Hbits.SHREN = 1;
    
    
    
}
int main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    
    // ADC INITIALIZATION 
    // Configure the I/O pins to be used as analog inputs.
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1;
    TRISBbits.TRISB2 = 1;
    ANSELAbits.ANSELA0 = 1;
    ANSELBbits.ANSELB2 = 1;
    
    // Configure the common ADC clock.
    ADCON3Hbits.CLKSEL = 2;
    ADCON3Hbits.CLKDIV = 0;
    
    // Configure the cores? ADC clock.
    ADCON2Lbits.SHRADCS = 0;
    
    // Configure the ADC reference sources.
    ADCON3Lbits.REFSEL = 0;
    
    // Configure the integer of fractional output format.
    ADCON1Hbits.FORM = 0;
    
    // Select single-ended input configuration and unsigned output format.
    ADMOD0Lbits.SIGN0 = 0;
    ADMOD0Lbits.DIFF0 = 0;
    ADMOD0Lbits.SIGN1 = 0;
    ADMOD0Lbits.DIFF1 = 0;
    
    // Enable and calibrate the module.
    EnableAndCalibrate();
    
    // Configure and enable ADC interrupts.
    ADIELbits.IE0 = 1;
    ADIELbits.IE1 = 1;
    _ADCAN0IF = 0;
    _ADCAN0IE = 1;
    
    _ADCAN1IF = 0;
    _ADCAN1IE = 1;
    
    // Set same trigger source for all inputs to sample signals simultaneously.
    ADTRIG0Lbits.TRGSRC0 = 12;
    ADTRIG0Lbits.TRGSRC1 = 12;
    
    // TIMER 1 INITIALIZATION (TIMER IS USED AS A TRIGGER SOURCE FOR ALL CHANNELS).
    T1CONbits.TCS = 0;
    T1CONbits.TCKPS = 0;
    PR1 = 0x8000;
    T1CONbits.TON = 1;
    
    while (1)
    {
        // Add your application code
    }
    return 1; 
}

void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _ADCAN0Interrupt(void)
{
  
    ADC_result_0 = ADCBUF0;
    _ADCAN0IF = 0;
   
}   
void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _ADCAN1Interrupt(void)
{
    ADC_result_1 = ADCBUF1;
    _ADCAN1IF = 0;
}
```

Comment: Title says "dsPIC33CK64MP508" but question body says dsPIC33CK64MC105. Which is it?

Comment: sorry iam using dsPIC33CK64MC105 controller